# git remote history after force push

Tags: git

My local repository contains all commits.
recently someone has cleared all the code in the remote repository and committed.
now i want to push my local code to repository.

When i try to push (git push origin master) i got error

```
(non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://myurl.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull') before pushing again.
```

when i tried  'git origin pull master' in log it shows several files are deleted.
i reverted by using hard reset@{14:30}.

it is advised to use git push -f origin master.
**if i perform force push command will my remote history will be same as my local history?**

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: yes.  This will throw away some history in the remote repository, and replace it with the history you have.  **You probably should not do this.**

Longer:

> recently someone has cleared all the code in the remote repository and committed.

That means this someone, whoever he is, has the ability to remove your commits.  Even if you put them back exactly as they were via `git push --force`, what is to stop this someone from removing them again?  Meanwhile, what will *he* think of *your* action of removing *his* commits?  The two of you will be conducting a sort of war over this remote repository.  **Is this a good idea?**

> it is advised to use git push -f origin master.

Advised by whom?

Remember that history, in a Git repository, is nothing *but* commits, as found via branch names (and tag names and other names).  The commits are numbered.  The numbers *look* random (but actually are not); each number is unique to that one particular commit.  The numbers are expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).

Each commit itself has two parts:

- A commit has a full snapshot of every file.  This makes the commit stand alone, as it were: if you have the commit, you have all of its files.  Otherwise (you don't have the commit), you have none of its files.
- And, a commit has some *metadata:* information about the commit itself, such as who made it, and when (author and committer name-and-email and two date-and-time stamps).  Included in this metadata, each commit records the raw commit number(s) of its immediate predecessor(s).

In this way, commits form backwards-looking chains.  In a tiny repository, with just three commits, we might have this:

```
A <-B <-C   <--master
```

where the uppercase letters stand in for the hash IDs of the commits.

What you're suggesting here is that someone has discarded some commit(s) and put in at least one *new* commit:

```
A <-D   <--master
```

If you use `git push --force master`, you'll send them—the repository over at `origin`—commits `B` and `C` again:

```
A <-B <-C
 \
  D   <--master
```

and then *command* them, rather than asking them politely, to make their `master` point to commit `C` again:

```
  D
 /
A <-B <-C   <--master
```

Commit `D` is now "lost" (*unreachable* is the technical term) because the way Git *finds* commits is to start with a name, such as `master`, that points to the *last* commit in some series, and then work backwards.  The result of working backwards is a list of commits.  This is the history.

By making the *name* point to a different *last* commit, you change history.  If your change merely *adds a new commit*, this *adds history:*

```
A <-B <-C <-E   <--master
```

This would add on to the `A-B-C` history, producing an `E-C-B-A` history as seen by working backwards from the end.

The force option with `push` means *I know this discards some history; do it anyway* and the receiving Git can either obey this or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
git push -f origin master
```

should work for you,The git command above works safely only for the first commit. If there were already commits, pull requests or branches in previous, this resets all of it and set it from zero

Answer (score 0):

If you force push to the branch that would make the remote history same as your local history.

To save yourself from this issue you can use the protected branch feature which doesn't allow force push on the branches, that is advisable for master or default branch so no one can remove the code by force pushing.

**Update:**

It would also depend on how the other user has removed all the code, if he has removed the code and force pushed then you will have to force push again but he has just deleted all the code, committed and then pushed then you can `revert` his commit which would not require any force push. You can revert using:

```
git revert <commit-hash>
```

You will have to update your branch with the remote branch first.

And if you are not sure about all this just backup your folder and then perform the experiments.